# Ruby on Rails ActionMailer Images Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to use embedded images in my E-Mail, but if I try to load a file from my image folder as a header, it's not displaying in the email:

The image is an inline attachment:

```
def export_bill_email(user)
        @user = user
        attachments.inline["logo.jpg"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/bdh_caption_logo.jpg")
        make_bootstrap_mail(
            to: 'xxx',
            from: 'xxx',
            subject: 'xxx'
        )
    end
```

Then in my view, I try to call it the following way:

```
<%= image_tag(attachments["logo.jpg"].url, width: '100', height: '100') %>
```

Is it not displaying cause of development mode? I also tried forwarding with ngrok, but still, it's just displaying a broken image sign in my received email.
The strange thing is: If I use a direct hyperlink to an image, it is displayed so it has to do something with the image URL I guess, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for any good advice!

Comment: did you try to set `mime_type: "image/png"` on this image? maybe there is an issue with mime type
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#adding-attachments

Comment: I tried it, but Rails will anyway guess the right mime type as of Rails 5 I guess. I could use the asset host method in my environment file, but this way I had to host the images like forever so they get displayed correctly in the mails.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it working in production, I think the problem is that the image can't bei downloaded from localhost cause it's not publically accessible by the mail client. If I run it on my Webserver it's working fine.